# Spring <jee:remote-slsb> and JBoss AS7 - No EJB receiver available for handling

Tags: spring, ejb, jboss7.x

I have got @Remote EJB on JBoss AS 7, available by name `java:global/RandomEjb/DefaultRemoteRandom!pl.lechglowiak.ejbTest.RemoteRandom`.

Standalone client is Spring application that uses `<jee:remote-slsb>` bean.
When trying to use that bean I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:RandomEjb, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1a89031`.

Here is relevant part of applicationContext.xml:

```
<jee:remote-slsb id="remoteRandom"
    jndi-name="RandomEjb/DefaultRemoteRandom!pl.lechglowiak.ejbTest.RemoteRandom"
    business-interface="pl.lechglowiak.ejbTest.RemoteRandom"
    <jee:environment>
        java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
        java.naming.provider.url=remote://localhost:4447
        jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
        java.naming.security.principal=testuser
        java.naming.security.credentials=testpassword
    </jee:environment>
</jee:remote-slsb>

<bean id="remoteClient" class="pl.lechglowiak.RemoteClient">
    <property name="remote" ref="remoteRandom" />
</bean>
```

RemoteClient.java
    public class RemoteClient {

```
private RemoteRandom random;

public void setRemote(RemoteRandom random){
    this.random = random;
}

public Integer callRandom(){
    try {
        return random.getRandom(100);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

My jboss client jar:
    
    org.jboss.as
    jboss-as-ejb-client-bom
    7.1.2.Final
    pom

pl.lechglowiak.ejbTest.RemoteRandom is available for client application classpath.
jndi.properties contains exact properties as in `<jee:environment>` of `<jee:remote-slsb>`.

Such code runs without exception:

```
Context ctx2 = new InitialContext();
RemoteRandom rr = (RemoteRandom)  ctx2.lookup("RandomEjb/DefaultRemoteRandom!pl.lechglowiak.ejbTest.RemoteRandom");
System.out.println(rr.getRandom(10000));
```

But this:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
RemoteClient client = ctx.getBean("remoteClient", RemoteClient.class);
System.out.println(client.callRandom());
```

ends with exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:, moduleName:RandomEjb, distinctName:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@1a89031.

`jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true` is set.
Do you have any idea what am I setting wrong in `<jee:remote-slsb>`?

Comment: This is a improvement https://jira.primekey.se/browse/ECA-3607

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a very similar problem. Have you created a "jboss-ejb-client.propeties" file?

If not, check out these:
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI (particularly the "Setting up EJB client context properties" sub-topic)

https://community.jboss.org/message/740827

https://community.jboss.org/thread/197989

You should place the file in the classpath of your client. Here is an simple example of what it could look like:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=4447
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

remote.connection.default.username=login
remote.connection.default.password=password
```

Good luck!

PS: The only project-specific values in this configuration would be the "username" and "password".

PS2: And just in case you haven't added a user to your jboss set-up, it's done through the "bin/add-user.[bat/sh]" script, located at your jboss folder.

Answer (score 0):

Set `expose-access-context="true"` to jee:remote-slsb taglib.

Answer (score 0):

using 
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming 
instead of 
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory